# Freemarker element from list not working

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I have a bean that has an array list of other beans, and I wan to print the value of one of the arraylist beans variables.  My ftl looks like this:

```
${applicationDocument.signatureCoordinatesAsDto[0].X}
```

my Java looks like this:

```
logger.debug("bean length:"+bean.getSignatureCoordinatesAsDto().size());
logger.debug("X:"+bean.getSignatureCoordinatesAsDto().get(0).getX());
model.addObject("applicationDocument", bean);
```

My logs have the correct output,  I have several beans in the array, and the .get(0).getX() returns the correct data. (And yes the X is defined as int X in the bean.)

Why is the ftl throwing  "Evaluates to null" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use small `x`

```
${applicationDocument.signatureCoordinatesAsDto[0].x}
```